# Using rtags for indexing firefox source code

Tags: firefox, cmake, clang

I am using [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags) which is a C++ source code indexer based on clang. I have been able to play around with it and now I want to actually index the firefox source code. I am pretty new to this stuff and this tool uses cmake to generate a [compile_commands.json](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) file to pass over to the program that indexes code.

Is there a way I can generate a the `compile_commands.json` file for the firefox source code that provides the exact compilation line for each translation unit inside the firefox source?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate `compile_commands.json` by

```
mozilla_cnetral/mach build-backend -b CompileDB
```

In my environment(Ubuntu 16.04), it was created at `mozilla_cnetral/obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/`.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Editor_Configuration#rtags_(LLVMClang-based_Code_Indexing)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I follow the part "Is there a way I can generate a the compile_commands.json file for the firefox source code that provides the exact compilation line for each translation unit inside the firefox source?". But I can offer simply that you can generate a compile_commands.json file from a make-based system using the bear utility (which I obtained from my package manager: brew). After a make clean, I do 'bear --append make' and it traces the make build process and produces the compile_commands.json. More can be learned here: https://vxlabs.com/2016/04/11/step-by-step-guide-to-c-navigation-and-completion-with-emacs-and-the-clang-based-rtags/

As the article referenced implies, my motivation was to be able to use the wonderful rtag system inside Emacs. Hope this helps a bit.